# Mouse pointer moving on arrow keys pressed in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, mouse

I'm encountering a strange problem on my W10 computer, for a few days my arrow keys have been "driving" my mouse pointer. Pressing the left arrow key will move the pointer a few pixels left, etc.

The first thing that came to my mind was "Oh well, I must have enabled Mouse Keys inadvertently". But Mouse Keys use the numpad and even then, it's not enabled. Rebooting doesn't help, but ***I've noticed it doesn't happen if the current window is ran as another user (Administrator)*** or if it's the Task Manager, which suggests the event filter that's catching the key press events is only active on my UID.

*I've tried killing various processes but I'm running out of ideas. Could someone suggest some fix for this strange behaviour?*

Comment: @harrymc After reading about the stupid bug of MS Paint below your comment/question (even though truly natural) made me laugh. In some sense, Safe Mode is another bug of Microsoft.

Comment: Sometimes pressing F7 undoes this mode of the cursor-via-keys.

Comment: TL;DR Close all the instances of the Paint Programs, See the magic!

Answer (score 874, accepted):

Tried killing all running processes on my PC till the problem went away and I can now say for sure the culprit was...

## Microsoft Paint

(classic Win32 one)

Apparently it's got a feature that allows moving the mouse pointer using arrow keys, and for some reason sometimes it doesn't stop listening when the window loses focus, so Paint was running in the background since I often use it and it was still doing its job of moving the mouse.

This also explains why the problem can persist **after a reboot**: when you reboot Windows while Paint is running, Windows will automatically "save your work" and **reopen Paint** at system boot, **causing the bug again**!

Comment: Thank you so much, I've searched for this quite a while. Never did i expect paint to be the culprit.  (I Replaced mspaint.exe with a mspaint from a windows10 1806 version and it doesn't do this behavior anymore.)
According to: https://winaero.com/blog/microsoft-is-updating-paint-with-new-accessibility-features/  Its a new feature in 1903

Comment: I'm glad this website exists! I didn't think I'd find the answer this quick.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much, that answers the question why mouse cursor only moves on some strange small square. And seems it occurs only when you have several MSPaint running and wake up your laptop from sleep several times.

Comment: (In my case) I guess Paint was open before my crash. After the crash, when windows recovered what it could of my session, this was suddenly happening. Closing Paint worked for me too. Thanks!

Comment: probably it can have something to do with remote desktop

Comment: Normally when I stumble across similar issues to what I'm having on these kinds of things, the weirdly specific solutions never worked. This is the weirdest solution I've come across and lo and behold, killing paint fixed it for me too :D

Comment: This just fixed it for me too. I didn't even see it running. You can kill them all with this powershell 1-liner `ps | where Name -like '*paint*' | % { $_.Kill() }`

Comment: it's a good hack to control your mouse cursor through keyboard macros though. Very useful feature(?) when you DO know about it!

Comment: Happens if the paint was automatically reopened after a forced update!

Comment: Add another victim to the list, thank you - I was checking accessibility/ease of access and finding nothing.

Comment: And another victim here too. I use mspaint constantly for screen shots, and it's never happened before. Very strange.

Comment: Same here, only on "recovered" paint sessions after Microsoft forcibly shuts down your pc and kills all your work when you walk away. I'm switching to Linux.

Comment: No need to kill paint -- just focus the window, maybe do something, and your mouse will be yours again.

Comment: This seems to be related to restoring a session - like on bootup, crash recovery, remote desktop etc. When it restores windows, Paint for some reason doesn't get the message that it's minimised so it takes over.

Comment: @PlausibleSarge yeah! probably this, it happened exactly to me - I rebooted my machine because of Windows Update and when it got back with Paint open I noticed that weird issue. I honestly thought Windows Update broke something, again.

Comment: `pskill mspaint` if you have sysinternals installed.

Comment: I was incredulous at first, but killing ms paint worked. So this is still an issue in Feb 2021.

Comment: It happened to me when restarting Windows without closing MS Paint first. Just closing the window fixed it.

Comment: I had a similar but related bug where arrow keys teleported my mouse to the bottom right hand corner of my screen. Checked, and found that Pain was running. Closing fixed this bug as well.

Comment: Using mspaint a lot, and first time such thing happened to me now so didn't even suspect this simple piece of software. And I'm not surprised even a bit, it's typical bug of Microsoft. Thanks, and glad to share some of my rep as a well deserved bonus. :-)

Comment: Just encountered this after 20+ years of Windows usage for the first time. I don't have a slightest idea how anyone figured this out.

Comment: Let me join the list of people thanking you. Beginner programmer mistake on the part of the Paint team.

Comment: still happens on win10 in 2022. Win11 has mspaint rewritten, hopefully it's fixed there

Comment: Do not need to kill paint (like someone said in the comments). Just switch focus to another option in the ribbon, like the "Select" button. It's a graphics glitch and it goes away once you perform an action within Paint.

Comment: Just had this happen. I noticed that the cursor would only move in a small (~400x500 px) area of my screen - holding the arrow key down, it would stop at a specific boundary. So I started minimizing windows, looking for any that appeared to correspond with that boundary. Lo and behold, the backmost window was "Untitled (Recovered) - Paint"!

Comment: An additional detail that you may want to add to your answer: Before I came across this question, I found another page that offered Scroll Lock as a suggestion. It turns out that I didn't have to close Paint, just toggling Scroll Lock completely resolved the behavior (even after turning it back off).

Comment: @Navin Still an issue in January 2023.

Comment: Just ran into this! 2023-04-20

Comment: I thought my computer was demonically infested for a second there. But no, just a glitch in Paint.

Comment: Microsoft are the #1 largest software company in the world.

Comment: I was facing the same issue today, thanks to zdimension and StackOverflow! I can't believe this bug still exists after so many years!

Comment: for me it was enough to refocus on the Paint window, then some other window, so no process killing was necessary. But thanks a lot! I would not have guessed where to look for the issue.