# How to disable mouse cursor control using arrows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, mouse-cursor

I did something and now the mouse pointer moves when I press the arrow keys. This is very inconvenient, for example, when editing text. In the operating system settings, keyboard pointer management is disabled. Perhaps this is due to the laptop model. How to disable it?

OS: Windows 10. Notebook: MSI GL72M 7REX

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mouse pointer moving on arrow keys pressed](https://superuser.com/questions/1467313/mouse-pointer-moving-on-arrow-keys-pressed). It's also possible that another one of the applications running on your computer provides this functionality.

Comment: @Romen, oh, that sounds like the truth. I really had Microsoft Paint open.

Comment: Same problem.  With Paint open, the arrow keys move the mouse cursor.  Sounds like a 1993 bug, not a 2023 bug. smh

Answer (score 3):

Look in Settings, Ease of Access, Mouse category, and turn OFF "Control your mouse with Keypad"  That should help you with this issue
If this problem is the same thing I had where it was normal arrow keys and not the ones on the numpad, it has something to do with paint. Close your paint.

Comment: Thank you, MS Paint was exactly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the system language from Russian to English to show that my "Control your mouse with Keypad" parameter is already disabled. But after updating the system language and rebooting the system, the problem disappeared. I did not change the mouse settings.